# Monaca iOS Publish error. Reason: Error publishing to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, monaca

Does anyone know how to get the log for the failure when submitting apps to App Store through Monaca via iTunes connect?

It says there is a iOS Publish Error but cannot get the reason and their support did not help on time. Not sure whether it is possible to view the logs within their system to identify the issue.

Still evaluating whether it is worth paying for the service from Monaca.

Comment: Not sure about your issue. Can you successfully build a release app using Monaca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/MonacaApp.app/MonacaApp' is not supported

I had to remove Associated Domains from App ID provisioning.